# mod_rewrite - .htaccess help needed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to configure the .htaccess file to do the following:

1. block directory listing if no index file is there
2. rewrite all requests to go to https
3. strip www and re-route to https://example.com
4. remove .php extentions from files:
   a) https://example.com/contact should internally route to https://example.com/contact.php
   b) https://example.com/phpfile/1234 should internally route to https://example.com/phpfile.php?id=1234
   c) I also need a way to re-route on some pages with 2 or even 3 variables like:
   https://example.com/otherphpfile.php?param1=101&param2=xxxx

This is what I have so far:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

I covered 1,2,3,4a... need an elegant way for 4b and 4c that is not bound to a specific file/path. it needs to work on any php files that can accept 1 or more params.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can check this link : http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: 4b.
`RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/?$   https://example.com/$1.php?id=$2 [L,R=301,NC]`

Should do it?

Comment: Better to route `/otherphpfile/101/xxxx` or `/otherphpfile/101/xxxx/yyyy` to just `/otherphpfile.php` without any GET parameter and let your PHP code parse `REQUEST_URI`

Answer (score 0):

For 4b, use as

```
RewriteRule ^phpfile/([^/]*)$ /phpfile.php?id=$1 [L]

Example :
Original URL : https://example.com/phpfile.php?id=123
Rewrite URL : https://example.com/phpfile/123
```

For 4c, use as

```
RewriteRule ^otherphpfile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /otherphpfile.php?param1=$1&param2=$2 [L]

Example :
Original URL : https://example.com/otherphpfile.php?param1=1234&param2=abcd
Rewrite URL : https://example.com/otherphpfile/1234/abcd
```

Comment: any idea why RewriteRule ^phpfile/([^/]*)$ /phpfile.php?id=$1 [L] doesn't work??? I get a "The page isn’t redirecting properly" "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: https://example.com/phpfile.php?id=123 works<br>https://example.com/phpfile/123 doesn't

Comment: RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC] inplace of this : RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off and check if that helps.